# Как считать UTF-8 файл посимвольно и в чем хранить символы?

Tags: java, utf-8, unicode

В интернете информации навалом но везде способы разные.
Как с найменьшим уровнем абстракции считать файл по unicode code point?
И в чем хранить в java unicode code point?
Все это с учетом того что файл может быть достаточно большой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придётся выбирать классы, позволяющие указать кодировку входного потока.
К сожалению получается несколько длинновато.

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(pathToFile), "UTF-8"));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
int r;
while ((r = in.read(cbuf, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
    sb.append(cbuf, 0, r);
}
String s = sb.toString();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length();) {
    int cp = s.codePointAt(i); // Unicode code point
    ...
    i += Character.charCount(cp);
}
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Допустим символ == unicode code point. В самом unicode определены возможные значения, грубо говоря, от 0 до 10FFFF. 32 бита хватает с некоторым избытком.
В java code point хранится в int.

В Java Tutorial настоятельно рекомендуется пользоваться code point вместо char. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/design.html
char всего 16 бит и не может охватить всё пространство unicode без каких-то ухищрений - большой code point может быть представлен суррогатной парой char.

Но метода для считывания code point и сам не припомню.
Как же тогда считать посимвольно (code point)?

1) Считывать по-char-но с кодировкой UTF-8, проверяя обычный ли char получен и его код совпадает с code point-ом, или суррогат и следующий должен быть парным суррогатом. Тогда при получении второго парного из них двоих получить один code point.
Используется стандартный декодер UTF-8, но на суррогатных char выполняется лишняя работа. С учётом того, что это довольно редкие символы, то вполне приемлемо.

2) Считывать побайтно и согласно правилам кодирования UTF-8 поток байт переводить в code point.
Здесь самостоятельно реализуется декодер UTF-8. Ничего лишнего. Но самому разбирать UTF, когда есть готовый и "плохие" символы редки. Может ну его на фиг?

Comment: Сам я розбирать utf-8 не хочу уж точно, в C с эти я наиградася. Считывать по char или что-то подобное это слижком низкий уровень абстпакции, я хочу готовый какойнить streamreader который мне считыет посимвольно файл с учетом utf-8, я увидел несколько этих streamreader'ов и подобных классов не знаю какой выбрать, вот среди них и нужно мне тот у которого уровень абстракции пониже но всеже чтоб считывание посимвольно происходило не боле чем в строчек 10-20 и без своих велосипедов

Comment: Что не так, если прочитать файл в `String s` (всё равно же хранить хотите) и извлекать code point-ы из строки? `int cp = s.codePointAt(i);` `i` от `0` до `s.length() - 1` следующий `i = i + Character.charCount(cp)`

Comment: О, не знал что так можно, только как два дня на java пишу, спасибо, а чем в таких простых случаях читать файл чтоб побыстрее, а то классов для элементарного чтения файлов несколько и везде по разному читают.

Comment: Вы путаете UTF-8 и UTF-16. В 8 нет никаких суррогатных пар.